# custom dropdown menu appearing below other elements on form

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, z-index

I have a form where a custom dropdown component that I built dynamically appears after a user has selected an option in another dropdown menu (which is the same component being reused), but the menu for the dynamically appearing dropdown menu is being hidden below other elements on the form after it so the user can't see the options.  The menu and options are showing up just fine for the same component when it is not dynamically loaded before in the form.  Below are some screen shots.  Any idea as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot of the form with the customer dropdown]

**Below is my code:**
Note that this custom component allows a user to input text but also select from options from the dropdown which filter as they user types.  The parent componenent is the "container" whose style is specified as "containerstyle".  All other elements are children.  The dropdown menu is positioned as "absolute".  Parent container is positioned as "relative":

```
 const containerstyle={
      position: "relative",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      get display(){if(layout=="stacked"){return "block"}else{return "flex"}},
      width: "100%",
      height: height || 58,
    }
  
    const inputStyle ={
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: valueSize || 16,
      fontWeight: valueBold || "normal",
      color: valueColor || "black",
      backgroundColor: fill || "white",
      outline: "none",
      width: width || "100%",
      height: height || "100%",
    }
  
    const labelStyle ={
      fontSize: labelSize || inputStyle.fontSize-3,
      fontWeight: labelBold || "normal",
      color: labelColor || "rgb(145, 145, 145)",
      padding: padding || 5,
      marginRight: 10,
    }
  
  
    const dropDownStyle = {
      display: dropDownDisplay,
      position: "absolute",
      top: containerstyle.top+containerstyle.height,
      left: inputStyle.left,
      width: "100%",
      minHeight: 300,
      maxHeight: 300,
      overflowY: "auto",
      overflowX: "hidden",
      padding: padding || 5,
      display: dropDownDisplay,
      backgroundColor: dropDownFill || "rgba(255,255,255,0.95)",
      boxShadow: "5px 5px 5px lightgray",
      border: "1px solid lightgray",
      borderRadius: "0px 0px 5px 10px",
      color: valueColor || "black",
      zIndex: 999999
    }
  
    const optionsStyle = {
      display: "block",
      width: "100%",
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: inputStyle.fontSize,
      fontWeight: optionWeight || "normal",
      padding: padding || 5,
      color: optionColor || "black",
      backgroundColor: fill || "rgb(255,255,255,0)",
    }
```

Comment: I figured out a fix for this.  When I dynamically load the new component I need to set it's zindex to a higher value in the html markup.  For example:  style={{zIndex:99999}}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix for my own questions. When I dynamically load the new component I need to set it's zindex to a higher value in the html markup. For example: style={{zIndex:99999}

React code when the component dynamically loads:

```
  {subcategories.length>0 &&
        <div className="form-floating mb-3 has-validation animate__animated animate__slideInDown animate__duration-0.5s" style={{zIndex:99999}}>
          <SuperInput
            id = "subcategory" 
            name="subcategory" 
            list={subcategories}
            value={initialFormData.subcategory}
            valueColor="#2C7BFF"
            onChange={handleChange} 
            label={"Select spend subcategory"}
            required={true}
            />
        </div>
```

Screenshot of fixed solution:

[image]